# How do I split a string using a regex?

Tags: regex, haskell

I’d like to split a string using a regular expression. I have browsed the various regex modules on Hackage, but I can’t make any sense of them. (I have noticed `Data.List.Split`, but it doesn’t seem to offer what I need, either.)

Comment: It's crazy how hard it is to just use a regular expression, for a trivial string operation, in Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
ghci > import Text.Regex.Posix
ghci > getAllTextMatches ("good food" =~ ".ood" :: AllTextMatches [] String)
["good","food"]
```

Real world haskell book has a nice [chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/efficient-file-processing-regular-expressions-and-file-name-matching.html) on it.

Comment: This isn't "splitting" a string in the normal sense, it's "matching" and extracting those matches.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell we often use monadic parsers instead of regex for pattern matching.

See [`splitCap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:splitCap)

```
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Data.Void

splitCap (some letterChar) "I'd like...a string"
```

```
[Right "I",Left "'",Right "d",Left " ",Right "like",Left "...",Right "a",Left " ",Right "string"]
```